# Slow rendering of Angular table with 1,000 rows and 5,000 inputs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying an Angular table with approx ~1,000 rows and 5 inputs per row (total of 5,000 input fields). It is a standard Angular table with ng-repeat for the rows.

The data is downloaded to the client quickly. BUT - the problem is slow Angular rendering.

On a MacBook Pro, it takes 10 seconds to load. On a Chromebook, it takes over 40 seconds.

I'm looking for a way to lazy RENDER. I'm sure that many of you have had this problem - can anyone point me to possible solutions?

Comment: use pagination and edit on demand within cells to avoid all the watches on inputs

Comment: We're using live search so we want to avoid pagination. Can you give an example of how to create "edit on demand"? We have both mobile (touch) users as well as laptop that want to tab across the input fields (similar to an Excel type sheet).

Comment: pagination doesn't mean you can't also use filtering. One example of edit in place would be `x-editable`

Comment: How do you set up filtering with live search? (Sorry for questions, still getting used to Angular)

Comment: lots of examples of  that around using angular filter including in docs. Also numerous table/grid modules around with features you mention

Comment: Could you kindly refer to one or two that you've seen? I haven't been able to locate an efficient solution for live search with limit filter. Thank you!!

Comment: not looking very hard... leave the term `live` out...most modules will include `search` ability. Filtering is very simple in angular

Comment: http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=8

Answer (score 2):

1. Use pagination
2. Only add inputs per row using edit template and an edit button
3. User $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false) to remove debug classes
4. Try utilising the ID of your items by adding "track by"
5. If you have values that you only read, use bind once `{{::property}}`
6. If you have many form fields try `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }`
7. Use ng-if instead of ng-show where possible to avoid adding many things that are not displayed
8. Use limitTo with your ng-repeat to limit the number of items displayed
9. Use chrome dev toolbar timeline to identify bottlenecks in your functions

[One of many good resources on our lovely web](http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/)

[And another one](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)

Answer (score 2):

Because the problem is with the rendering you could use a filter to limit the number of fields that ng-repeat returns. Then just paginate the extra rows.

Comment: ah yeah forgot limit to. This is also a very good way of speeding things up. Nice one!

Comment: if its ok i will add it to my answer too. I gave you an upvote so should be ok :)

Comment: I forgot to add - we're using live search. How can I filter to render those rows that are only visible on the screen?